Flutter: How to set default keyboard language for textfield
Is there any way I can set the default language for some text fields in my application to only use the keyboard of a certain language like English?
Thank you!

Did you find any solution?

@GeorgiyChebotarev No. I had to custom English keyboard for this text field

Thx. I was too. Just changed hint text

Hello with in the MaterialApp you can specify the language like this
MaterialApp(
      locale: Locale('en', 'US'),
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );

Hope it will work

Thank you. but I just want a few special text fields that can only be entered in English. The remaining text fields can still be used in other languages

Until you find a straightforward answer or a (Future Update)
You can notify the user with a helper text ex: English Language only
And restrict your input to be english characters only by using regular expression:
TextField(
   inputFormatters: [
            FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow(RegExp("[a-zA-Z]"))
       ])

Hope it helps you.

Thank you. I tried FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow(RegExp("[0-9a-zA-Z]"). But it gives me a duplicate number error when I try to enter the number using the Japanese keyboard, so I want the keyboard language to be only English.
